# Why are Hamilton's equations sometimes written with a gradient?

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, notation, phase-space

I am used to seeing Hamilton's written as:
$$\frac{dq_j}{dt} = \frac{\partial H}{\partial p_j}\\
\frac{dp_j}{dt} = - \frac{\partial H}{\partial q_j}.$$

However I have also seen it written as
$$\frac{dq_j}{dt} = \nabla_{p_i} H\\
\frac{dp_j}{dt} = - \nabla_{q_i}H.$$

Why introduce the $\nabla$ here? I thought the first set of equations is already sufficiently general to $n$-dimensions. Or is this just a notational difference?

My best guess is that the latter is running the indices $i$ and $j$ over say an $n$-particle system, but is treating each $q_i$ and $p_i$ as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: It cannot understand two things related to this question: i) how people could classify this question as "opinion-based" (on the same basis a question about the use of a different notation between scalars and vectors should be matter of opinion) and ii) why the OP accepted inconsistent answer. I'll vote for reopening.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/714212/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/714447/2451

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best guess is correct. Let's take the example of an $N$ particle system in $\text{3D}$. If I wanted to define my generalized coordinates as just the position of each particle, then one way I could label them is:
$$q_1 = x_1, \quad q_2 = y_1, \quad q_3 = z_1, \quad q_4 = x_2\quad ,  ..., \quad q_{3N} = z_N.$$
In this case, I would write the equations of motion as
\begin{align}
&\dot{q}_j = \frac{\partial H}{\partial p_j}\\
&\dot{p}_j = - \frac{\partial H}{\partial q_j} \tag{1}
\end{align}
But, sometimes people like to bundle the coordinates for each particle into its own vector, i.e.
$$\mathbf{q}_1 = (x_1, y_1,z_1), \quad ,  ..., \quad \mathbf{q}_N = (x_N, y_N,z_N).$$
In this case, the equations of motion would be
\begin{align}
&\dot{\mathbf{q}}_j = \boldsymbol{\nabla}_{p_j} H\\
&\dot{\mathbf{p}}_j = -\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{q_j} H \tag{2}
\end{align}
so it's just a matter of convention.

**Response to GiorgioP's Comment**

To further clarify my point, suppose I have a system with an 8-dimensional phase space. Let's call some set of generalized coordinates for this system $q_1$, $q_2$, $q_3$ and $q_4$. I can just as well re-label these quantities as $\tilde{q}_{11} \equiv q_1$, $\tilde{q}_{12} \equiv q_2$, $\tilde{q}_{21} \equiv q_3$ and , $\tilde{q}_{22} \equiv q_4$. I'm just changing the way I'm referring to them. Then, Eq.$(1)$ would take the form
\begin{align}
&\dot{\tilde{q}}_{ij} = \frac{\partial H}{\partial {\tilde{p}}_{ij}}\\
&\dot{\tilde{p}}_{ij} = - \frac{\partial H}{\partial {\tilde{q}}_{ij}} \tag{3}
\end{align}
Now, if I wanted to, I could define the vectors $\mathbf{\tilde{q}}_j = (\tilde{q}_{1j},\tilde{q}_{2j})$, for $j \in \{1,2\}$, and then rewrite Eq.$(3)$ as
\begin{align}
&\dot{\mathbf{\tilde{q}}}_j = \boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\tilde{p}_j} H\\
&\dot{\mathbf{\tilde{p}}}_j = -\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\tilde{q}_j} H \tag{4}
\end{align}
It's just a matter of notational convenience. For example, I might want to bundle together all generalized coordinates of each subsystem into a separate vector, so that I can keep track of them easier (E.g. it's easier to see that $q_{3x}$ is the $x$ position of the third particle rather than $q_{7}$ in my first example).

To clarify, none of this requires that the generalized coordinates are *a-priori* components of a vector. $q_1$ might be some angle and $q_2$ might be some length for some subsystem, and you might still find it convenient to work with $\mathbf{q} = (q_1,q_2)$ so that you have all coordinates of that subsystem in one collection. I'm also not claiming that you can always do this kind of re-labeling (other than the trivial way of having single-element vectors of course).

Comment: I do not agree with your answer. What happens when the q's and p's are not the components of a vector?

Comment: @GiorgioP Sorry I can't really see what's inconsistent about this. I tried to clarify in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is, that it's a far more compact/applicable form of notation generalization, especially when dealing with various types of field theories (both classical or quantum).

In general, the Hamiltonian is used to probe all time-translational invariants of any given dynamical field theory; *e.g.* the canonical observables within phasespace, or the eigenvalue-spectrum for the time/energy- and position/momentum-observables, respectively. This basically means, that any physically measurable constants of motion, within any given dynamical system, are essentially all determined by the energy conservation requirement of Hamilton's equations.
And there exists a lot of different fundamental varieties of Hamilton's system of equations! Be they expressed as the Poisson bracket's symplectic behavior $\{H,\cdot\}$ in classical mechanics, or  as the (semi-simple) group-algebraic commutation relations for ergodic systems $[H,\cdot]$ in quantum mechanics. But my favorite version/application of Hamilton's equations is with out a doubt expressed as the Noether current in Liouville's theorem
\begin{align}
\frac{d\rho}{d t}&=\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}+\sum_{i=1}^N\left(\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial q_i}\dot{q}_i+\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial p_i}\dot{p}_i\right)\\
&=\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}+\sum_{i=1}^N\left(\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial q_i}\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial p^i}\right)+\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial p_i}\left(-\frac{\partial H}{\partial q^i}\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}+\nabla_{\bf{q}}\rho+\nabla_{\bf{p}}\rho=0
\end{align}
where the directional derivatives $\nabla_{\bf{q}}\rho=\nabla\rho\cdot\dot{\bf{q}}$ and $\nabla_{\bf{p}}\rho=\nabla\rho\cdot\dot{\bf{p}}$ are usually calculated using Greens- or Stokes theorem. My general point, however, is that the invariant Hamiltonian flow satisfies the condition
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}=-\{\rho,H\}.
\end{equation}
I hope I didn't stray to far from the topic towards the end, but I wanted to answer you thoroughly. Otherwise, just comment, and I'll try to elaborate further.